# $X^p-t\in\mathbb F_p(t)[X]$ is irreducible but has one root.

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I don't really understand the incredible thing with this polynomial.

i) In what it is a special polynomial ?

ii) Do you agree that $\mathbb F_p(t)=\{1,\sqrt[p]t,\sqrt[p]{t^2},...,\sqrt[p]{t^{p-1}}\}$ ?

Comment: Why do you believe it has a root in $\mathbb F_p(t)$? I disagree with ii) because it's wrong. Certainly as an equality of sets, but also if one takes the right hand side to mean the vector space spanned by these polynomials (RHS is finite-dimensional, LHS is infinite-dimensional). Also, the elements on the RHS are not even contained in $\mathbb F_q(t)$.

Comment: i) It is an irreducible polynomial (over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, in particular it has no root) however if you take this polynomial in the algebraic closure it has a multiple root of multiplicity $p$, such things cannot happen over fields of characteristic zero. ii) No I don't, $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ is an infinite field ($t$, $t^2$, $t^3$... are all different elements in it).

Comment: @moonlight: Why do you think that I think that it has one root in $\mathbb F_p(t)$ ? It's not what I wrote.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin: I see, but still has a mistakes. $\sqrt[p]t$ is the root of $X^p-t$, right ? Indeed, if $\alpha^p=t$ then $\alpha=\sqrt[p]t$ (I'm not sure about the notation). But why is it the only root ? And I guess the root is in $\mathbb F_p(\sqrt[p]t)$, is it an extension of degree $p$ ?

Comment: I am not sure why this polynomial is so 'incredible' either but this polynomial has one root. This is because the polynomial $X^p-1$ is inseparable in characteristic $p$ field.

Comment: Basically, you should first take the algebraic closure $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ then it is true that we may take a root of X^p-t in it namely $\alpha:=\sqrt[p]{t}$, it is defined. This is the only root because over $\Omega$ we have $X^p-t=X^p-\alpha^p=(X-\alpha)^p$ (beware there is something to prove here) so we see that $\alpha$ is the unique root of multiplicity $p$ of $X^p-t$...

Comment: ...This is somehow related to the fact that over a field of characteristic $p$ you have no such thing as a $p$-primitive root of the unity. Let me just add that $\alpha^2$ is not a root of $X^p-t$ (this is a mistake you seem to imply from what you write)

Comment: @Rick: I didn't realize you meant to ask why it has *only* one root (with multiplicity $p$), even in a splitting field.

Answer (score 2):

It's irreducible because over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, relative to the $t$-adic valuation, it is an *Eisenstein polynomial* (The proof of Eisenstein's criterion extends to this case too! Alternatively, you can read about the theory of the Newton Polygon). (There's probably an easier way to see that it's irreducible).

Either way, it certainly has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$. Obviously $\sqrt[p]{t}\notin\mathbb{F}_p(t)$.

It's special because it's an example of an irreducible polynomial with only one root (ie, an irreducible inseparable polynomial). Note that in a splitting field, it factors as $(X-\sqrt[p]{t})^p$. If you replace $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ with a field of characteristic 0 or prime to $p$, then it would factor as $\prod_{i=0}^p(X-\zeta_p^i\sqrt[p]{t})$, but over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, there are no $p$th roots of unity!

Exercise: Can you find an irreducible polynomial with only one root over $\mathbb{F}_p$?