# Finding irreducible polynomial which is not separable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, proof-explanation, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I am studying finite field theory and Galois theory from NPTEL lecture series on Galois Theory. Here I found an example and I ahve question related to that. The example is about an irreducible inseparable polynomial. Here it is :

Let us consider the field $\Bbb F_p (t)$ of rational functions over $\Bbb F_p$ with variable $t.$ Let us consider the polynomial $f(X)=X^p - t \in \Bbb F_p (t) [X].$ Then it is irreducible over $\Bbb F_p (t)$ but it is inseparable since $f'(X) = pX^{p-1} = 0$  in $\Bbb F_p(t)[X]$ as $\text{Char}\ (\Bbb F_p(t)) = p.$

Inseparability can be shown in other ways too. Let $x$ be a zero of $f(X)$ in some extension field. Then $x$ is algebraic over $\Bbb F_p(t).$ But then $\Bbb F_p(t)[x]$ is a field i.e. $\Bbb F_p(t)[x]=\Bbb F_p(t)(x).$

Now $\text{Char}\ (\Bbb F_p(t)(x))=p.$ So we have $$f(X)=X^p-t=X^p-x^p = (X-x)^p\ \text{in}\ \Bbb F_p(t)(x)[X].$$

So $x$ is a zero of $f(X)$ of multiplicity $p$ i.e. $f(X)$ is not separable.

My question is $:$ Is $f(X)$ not irreducible in $\Bbb F_p[t][X] = \Bbb F_p[t,X]$?

I have an idea regarding this. What we know is that a polynomial in $\Bbb Z[X]$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[X]$ iff it is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[X]$ and it is a primitive polynomial, where $\Bbb Q$ is the quotient field of $\Bbb Z.$ So what I think is that in our case $t$ is prime in $\Bbb F_p[t].$ So by Eisenstein's criterion it actually follows that $X^p-t$ is irreducible over the quotient field $\Bbb F_p[t]$ which is $\Bbb F_p(t).$ Also since $X^p-t$ is a primitive polynomial so it is irreducible in $\Bbb F_p[t][X] = \Bbb F_p[t,X].$ Am I correct in my argument?

Any valuable suggestion regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you check your idea with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761815/how-to-show-that-xp-t-in-mathbbf-ptx-is-irreducible?noredirect=1&lq=1), and the linked ones?

Comment: Sounds about right. Eisenstein's criterion is, indeed, useful for proving irreducibility of polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb{F}_p[t]$.